# mod_rewrite parameterized url suggestion

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've searched the many excellent articles on this and I don't quite get it yet, I think I'm close, but so far not quite.  I think my limited undestanding of regular expressions is what's holding me up.

Here's what I'm trying to redirect:

User enters this in to a browser:

http://www.example.com/appliances/toaster/(somepage).php

What I want the redirect to go to:

http://www.example.com/appliances/(somepage).php?appliance=toaster

It seems insanely simple, but I just can't get it yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this to the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^appliances/([^/]+)/([^/.]+)\.php$ /appliances/$2.php?appliance=$1 [L]
```

Of if you have an htaccess file in your `/appliances/` folder, add this to the htaccess file in there:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/.]+)\.php$ $2.php?appliance=$1 [L]
```

---

To make sure you've got all your links looking the way you want, you can also add this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /appliances/([^/.]+))\.php\?appliance=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /appliances/%2/%1.php? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thank you both, that just saved me a ton of time.  I was using a (.*) and getting it all confused.  How do I award credit?

Comment: So one last question on the best way to do this.  Now I just construct all my links in php using the http://www.example.com/appliances/toaster/(somepage).php format?  Which will be ok as long as I remember the format.  Is there any way to do this so it doesn't get so confusing with a big site/

Comment: @user3066948 yes, all of your links need to look like what you wanted to enter into the browser (without the `?` query string).

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(appliances)/([^/]+)/([^.]+\.php)$ /$1/$3?appliance=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```